# How do I call the system from a python code piping the data of a python created file?

Tags: python-3.x

I´m writing a Python code to print the size of some text files with the bash instruction:

```sh
$ du -b File.txt | cut -f 1
```

I need to do this many times with a call to the system, using subprocess.run, but can't insert in a dynamic way the name of the files. Tried `subprocess.run(['du', '-b', Texto.name, '|', 'cut', '-f', '1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` but doesn't work.

Do you have any idea? I have really searched for it in the internet without success. Thank you very much!

This is the code:

```
import subprocess
contadorBloques = 100
filename = 'thePurloinedLetter.txt'

for s in range(0, contadorBloques):
    Texto = open(filename[:-4] + str(s) +'.txt', 'r')
    Texto.close()
    result = subprocess.run(['du', '-b',  Texto.name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print (result.stdout)
```

This is the result I get:

```
b'502\tthePurloinedLetter0.txt\n'
b'501\tthePurloinedLetter1.txt\n'
b'500\tthePurloinedLetter2.txt\n'
b'500\tthePurloinedLetter3.txt\n'
b'500\tthePurloinedLetter4.txt\n'
b'500\tthePurloinedLetter5.txt\n'
b'500\tthePurloinedLetter6.txt\n'
...
```

cause the files are 500 b

What I want is 502, 501, 500, 500, ... in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this approach works:

```
import subprocess
contadorBloques = 100
filename = 'thePurloinedLetter.txt'

for s in range(0, contadorBloques):
    Texto = open(filename[:-4] + str(s) +'.txt', 'w')
    Texto.close()
    result = subprocess.getoutput("""du -g {} | cut -f 1""".format(filename))
    print(result)
```

Comment: It is close to work, just changing g, but when I do the change I get 100 times the size of thePurloinedLetter.txt file. When I change filename by Texto in .format(), I get 100 times this message: /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "|" unexpected

Comment: Ok, working good if I write result = subprocess.getoutput("""du -b {} | cut -f 1""".format(filename[:-4]+str(s) +'.txt')). Thank you so much.

Comment: @Xavier Please accept the answer if it answers your question